# JS filter array by array within

Tags: javascript, arrays, array-filter, arrayobject

I have an array as following

```
  [{
    "id": 68,
    "proffesional_photo": "",
    "top_image": "https://sampleimage.jpg",
    "ratings": "1",
    "price": 690,
    "description": null,
    "type": true,
    "promo": 0,
    "status": true,
    "item": {
      "Item_name": "Dark Chocolate Latte"
    },
    "restaurant_dish_menus": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "res_dish_id": 1318,
        "menu_id": 4,
        "createdAt": "2018-11-13T04:28:17.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2018-11-13T04:28:17.000Z"
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "res_dish_id": 1318,
        "menu_id": 3,
        "createdAt": "2018-11-13T04:28:17.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2018-11-13T04:28:17.000Z"
      }
     ]
  },
  {
    "id": 69,
    "proffesional_photo": "",
    "top_image": "https://sampleimage2.jpg",
    "ratings": "1",
    "price": 700,
    "description": null,
    "type": true,
    "promo": 0,
    "status": true,
    "item": {
      "Item_name": "Latte"
    },
    "restaurant_dish_menus": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "res_dish_id": 1318,
        "menu_id": 3,
        "createdAt": "2018-11-13T04:28:17.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2018-11-13T04:28:17.000Z"
      }
     ]
  }
  ],
```

And when the user select a certain menu it needs to be filtered through it,

Each dish objects may have more than one menu_id,

i attempted using `array.filter` but i am having trouble figuring out how to filter from the `Dish array` through the sub array within.

the code i attempted (`filterBy = 4`)

```
let result = data.filter(function(row) {
  row.restaurant_dish_menus.filter(function(i) {
    return i.menu_id == filterBy;
  });
});
```

`console.log(result)` gives me an empty array.

if `filterBy is = 4` the expected output is

```
{
    "id": 68,
    "proffesional_photo": "",
    "top_image": "https://sampleimage.jpg",
    "ratings": "1",
    "price": 690,
    "description": null,
    "type": true,
    "promo": 0,
    "status": true,
    "item": {
      "Item_name": "Dark Chocolate Latte"
    },
    "restaurant_dish_menus": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "res_dish_id": 1318,
        "menu_id": 4,
        "createdAt": "2018-11-13T04:28:17.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2018-11-13T04:28:17.000Z"
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "res_dish_id": 1318,
        "menu_id": 3,
        "createdAt": "2018-11-13T04:28:17.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2018-11-13T04:28:17.000Z"
      }
     ]
  }
```

And if it `filterBy` is 3 then both objects should be the output

Comment: Are you trying to filter an array of objects like the one in your first code snippet?

Comment: @MarkMeyer yeah the main array object should be filtered depending on if the `restaurant_dish_menus` array contains the passed `ID`

Comment: What is your expected outcome? Do  you expect an array of dishes or an array of menu items that contain the dish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how about this

```
var data =   [{
    "id": 68,
    "proffesional_photo": "",
    "top_image": "https://sampleimage.jpg",
    "ratings": "1",
    "price": 690,
    "description": null,
    "type": true,
    "promo": 0,
    "status": true,
    "item": {
      "Item_name": "Dark Chocolate Latte"
    },
    "restaurant_dish_menus": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "res_dish_id": 1318,
        "menu_id": 4,
        "createdAt": "2018-11-13T04:28:17.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2018-11-13T04:28:17.000Z"
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "res_dish_id": 1318,
        "menu_id": 3,
        "createdAt": "2018-11-13T04:28:17.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2018-11-13T04:28:17.000Z"
      }
     ]
  }];

  var result = data.filter(function(m) {
    return m.restaurant_dish_menus.some(function(d) {
      return d.menu_id === 4;
    });
  })
```

Answer (score 2):

`.filter` expects the function passed to return a boolean. In your case, the function returns nothing (or `undefined`) which is always falsy.

One option is to use `.find` in the nested filter, and return a boolean depending on whether the result is `undefined`.

Here's a snippet.

```js
let data = [{
  "id": 68,
  "proffesional_photo": "",
  "top_image": "https://sampleimage.jpg",
  "ratings": "1",
  "price": 690,
  "description": null,
  "type": true,
  "promo": 0,
  "status": true,
  "item": {
    "Item_name": "Dark Chocolate Latte"
  },
  "restaurant_dish_menus": [{
      "id": 1,
      "res_dish_id": 1318,
      "menu_id": 4,
      "createdAt": "2018-11-13T04:28:17.000Z",
      "updatedAt": "2018-11-13T04:28:17.000Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "res_dish_id": 1318,
      "menu_id": 3,
      "createdAt": "2018-11-13T04:28:17.000Z",
      "updatedAt": "2018-11-13T04:28:17.000Z"
    }
  ]
}, {
  "id": 69,
  "proffesional_photo": "",
  "top_image": "https://sampleimage.jpg",
  "ratings": "1",
  "price": 690,
  "description": null,
  "type": true,
  "promo": 0,
  "status": true,
  "item": {
    "Item_name": "Dark Chocolate Latte"
  },
  "restaurant_dish_menus": [{
      "id": 1,
      "res_dish_id": 1318,
      "menu_id": 6,
      "createdAt": "2018-11-13T04:28:17.000Z",
      "updatedAt": "2018-11-13T04:28:17.000Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "res_dish_id": 1318,
      "menu_id": 5,
      "createdAt": "2018-11-13T04:28:17.000Z",
      "updatedAt": "2018-11-13T04:28:17.000Z"
    }
  ]
}, ]

let filterBy = 4;

let result = data.filter(function(row) {
  return row.restaurant_dish_menus.find(function(i) {
    return i.menu_id == filterBy;
  }) !== undefined;
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use "filter" as below

```js
var data = [{
    "id": 68,
    "proffesional_photo": "",
    "top_image": "https://sampleimage.jpg",
    "ratings": "1",
    "price": 690,
    "description": null,
    "type": true,
    "promo": 0,
    "status": true,
    "item": {
      "Item_name": "Dark Chocolate Latte"
    },
    "restaurant_dish_menus": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "res_dish_id": 1318,
        "menu_id": 4,
        "createdAt": "2018-11-13T04:28:17.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2018-11-13T04:28:17.000Z"
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "res_dish_id": 1318,
        "menu_id": 3,
        "createdAt": "2018-11-13T04:28:17.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2018-11-13T04:28:17.000Z"
      }
     ]
  },
  {
    "id": 69,
    "proffesional_photo": "",
    "top_image": "https://sampleimage2.jpg",
    "ratings": "1",
    "price": 700,
    "description": null,
    "type": true,
    "promo": 0,
    "status": true,
    "item": {
      "Item_name": "Latte"
    },
    "restaurant_dish_menus": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "res_dish_id": 1318,
        "menu_id": 3,
        "createdAt": "2018-11-13T04:28:17.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2018-11-13T04:28:17.000Z"
      }
     ]
  }
  ]

function filterBy(f) {
    return data.filter(d => d.restaurant_dish_menus.some(({ menu_id }) => menu_id == f))
}

console.log(filterBy(4))

console.log(filterBy(3))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use grep function

```
var menus=  {
    "id": 68,
    "proffesional_photo": "",
    "top_image": "https://sampleimage.jpg",
    "ratings": "1",
    "price": 690,
    "description": null,
    "type": true,
    "promo": 0,
    "status": true,
    "item": {
      "Item_name": "Dark Chocolate Latte"
    },
    "restaurant_dish_menus": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "res_dish_id": 1318,
        "menu_id": 4,
        "createdAt": "2018-11-13T04:28:17.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2018-11-13T04:28:17.000Z"
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "res_dish_id": 1318,
        "menu_id": 3,
        "createdAt": "2018-11-13T04:28:17.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2018-11-13T04:28:17.000Z"
      }
     ]
  };

var found_names = $.grep(menus.restaurant_dish_menus, function(v) {
    return v.menu_id ===4;
});

console.log(found_names);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ejPV4/

Answer (score 0):

Your question a bit unclear of final goal, but if you want to filter top level objects, i.e. if top level object has to be present if and only if it has dish with `menu_id === filterBy`, then:

```
let result = data.filter(row => {
  return row.restaurant_dish_menus.some(({menu_id}) => menu_id === filterBy);
});
```

Above will only filter your rows if `restaurant_dish_menus` has items with `menu_id === filterBy`. But `restaurant_dish_menus`, of such objects remain unfiltered.

Result:

```
[{
  "id": 68,
  // skipped
  "item": {
    "Item_name": "Dark Chocolate Latte"
  },
  "restaurant_dish_menus": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "res_dish_id": 1318,
      "menu_id": 4,
      // skipped
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "res_dish_id": 1318,
      "menu_id": 3,
      // skipped
    }
  ]
}]
```

But if you want to filter top level and filter `restaurant_dish_menus` also, i.e. modify top level object, then:

```
let result = data.filter(row => {
  return row.restaurant_dish_menus.some(({menu_id}) => menu_id === filterBy);
}).map(row => {
  return {...row, restaurant_dish_menus: row.restaurant_dish_menus.filter(i => i.menu_id === filterBy)};
});
```

This will first filter the row objects which has `menu_id === filterBy`, and then also filter `restaurant_dish_menus`, to include only once `menu_id === filterBy`, effectively modifying the row object, i.e. `map`.

Result:

```
[{
  "id": 68,
  // skipped
  "item": {
    "Item_name": "Dark Chocolate Latte"
  },
  "restaurant_dish_menus": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "res_dish_id": 1318,
      "menu_id": 4,
      // skipped
    }
  ]
}]
```